# Page not found 404 on unauthorized URL when page not exists

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, http-status-code-404

I have following setup of Spring Security with default deny all (see example below). I don't want to change default deny all because it's defensive way of security configuration and it's also considered as good practice. Obviously if user want access some page that doesn't exist he gets 403 because default deny all strategy. I want result 404 when page not exists and 403 when user have restricted access. Is there a way to configure Spring Security for this behavior?

**Example :**

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/posts/remove" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/posts/add" access="hasRole('EDITOR')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/posts" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />

    <!-- Default is access denied -->
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
</http>
```

When user requests `/something-that-not-exists` he should get 404 (Not 403). When EDITOR user requests `/posts/remove` he should get 403.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if such configuration is possible, as the security filters intercept and process the request at an earlier stage before the URL mapping logic of your webapp could even get the chance to determine if there is any resource to respond with to that particular request.
If the security filter decides to deny access by matching the request URL, it will never turn out if there was a page behind that URL at all.

---

#### EDIT (response to Michal's comment):

Since the mapping of urls to resources/handlers is pretty much arbitrary in every application, no framework could possibly provide an algorithm that is generally applicable to every webapp and that could determine the outcome of the mapping process in advance.

If you can implement such logic for *your* webapp (e.g. by knowing its entire url space), you could very easily create the filter you suggested. If you happen to use Spring MVC, calling [`getHandler()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerMapping.html#getHandler(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)) on every `HandlerMapping` deployed in your application could help implementing such a filter.

Anyway, I guess providing this kind of facility cannot be in scope for a security library that is meant to be independent and capable of working with a wide range of different web frameworks.

Comment: You are right. I think the same, but it doesn't seems to me as a proper behavior. Maybe there should be a filter (or it should be part of security filter) that determine if url mapping even exists before deciding of security matters.

Comment: You're right zagyi. This is out of scope of security library. I have just Spring MVC request mapping in my mind so I missed this point of view :) I have mine entire url space separated anyway so it's easy for me (to check if url exists). I just don't want to reinvent wheel. Thanks.

Comment: I think you guys may be missing a subtle point. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19460289/166339).

Answer (score 2):

I think one of the assumptions you are making is incorrect. You said:

> When user requests /something-that-not-exists he should get 404 (Not 403)

This is in direct conflict with:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
```

because `/something-that-not-exists` is a protected resource **whether it exists or not**. As an unauthenticated user, you should not be able to ask the question "Does `/something-that-not-exists` contain a valid resource?" Doing so violates the security model. Imagine for example these hypothetical urls:

Suppose this url exists:

```
/admin/accounts/email/miles@example.com
```

Authenticated users should get a `200 OK` response. Unauthenticated users should be redirected to the login page.

Suppose now that this url *does not* exist:

```
/admin/accounts/email/coltrane@example.com
```

Authenticated users should get a `404 NOT FOUND` response. Unauthenticated users should be redirected to the login page.

If we returned `404` to unauthenticated users, we would expose a security hole where an attacker could query if users exist in the system by email address.

So you either need to rethink your assumption above or your `denyAll` rule because they are mutually exclusive.